# Is there a way to read files in bytes?

Tags: java, php, spring, base64

I am working on changing the code completed with php to java.
I have a test.tpf file encrypted with SEED and the file is encoded in ANSI.
The test.tpf file contains a string and image information for base64 encoding and output.
I have to cut 16 bytes each and read the file to decrypt test.tpf.
So I used fileInputStream to save and decrypt the bytes that I read in a 16-size byte array.

```
            int nReadCur=0;
            byte[] outbuf = new byte[16];
            int nRead =0;

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tpf);
                while (true) {            
                   byte[] fileContentArray=new byte[16];

                   nRead = fis.read(fileContentArray);
                   nReadCur = nReadCur + nRead;

                   seed.SeedDecrypt(fileContentArray, pdwRoundKey, outbuf); //Decryption
                   String dbgmsg =new String(outbuf,"MS949");
                   
                   mergeStr+=dbgmsg; 
                   if(nFileSize<=nReadCur || nRead==-1)
                      break;
                }//while
```

Then, they encoded the part corresponding to the image information in base64.
In js, the base64 code was changed to a string to receive the string and base64 information in json and display it on the screen.

```
                String[] dataExplode=mergeStr.split("<TextData>");
                String[] dataExplode1=dataExplode[1].split("</FileInfo>");
                String[] dataExplode2=dataExplode1[0].split("</TextData>");

                String textData = null;
                String imageData = null;
                
                textData=dataExplode2[0];
                imageData=dataExplode1[1];

            
            Encoder encoder=Base64.getEncoder();
            imageData=encoder.encodeToString(imageData.getBytes());
                
                JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
                ja.put(textData);
                ja.put(imageData);
            result.put("imageContent", ja);
```

However, it seems that the file cannot be read properly.
Compared to the result value of the php code I have, the string is incorrectly entered.
My Eclipse basic encoding is UTF8, so I think this problem is due to encoding.When I read files using fileInputStream, I wanted to set up characters and read them.
I don't know how to read bytes at this time.

How can I read files 16 bytes at a time after setting up the encoding?
Also, I would like to know if there is a mistake in my code.

My java version is 1.8 and I use spring 3.1.1

++)add

I succeeded in making a 16-size outbuf array into one array using the ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos =new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

.
.
.

        seed.SeedDecrypt(fileContentArray, pdwRoundKey, outbuf);

        baos.write(outbuf, 0, 16);
        break;   
    }
}//while

mergeStr=new String(baos.toByteArray(),"MS949");
.
.
.
```

However, compared to the php code I have, I found that the result value of php is different from the result value of java.

in java:`System.out.println("mergeStr:"+mergeStr.length()+" / image:"+imageData.length());`

java console: `mergeStr:69716 / image:168092`

in php:`alog("mergeStr: ".strlen($mergeStr)." / imageData : ".strlen($imageData ));`

php log: `mergeStr: 85552 / imageData: 111860`

Since the result string decoded by java and php is different, the result of java and php is different for the value encoded by imageData as base64

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file in bytes, there is no encoding.
Only when you convert/interprete the bytes as characters, encoding becomes important.

So if you want to stick to reading bytes, FileInputStream is the way.
If you want to read characters, a [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html) is the way.

Note you can specify the encoding to be used on the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.nio.charset.Charset)) - which is necessary if the file is not in the system default encoding.

**Edit**:
*How can I read files 16 bytes at a time after setting up the encoding?*

You simply cannot. But you can read 16 bytes, then [when you convert to String specify the encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.lang.String)).

Comment: Note that converting arbitrary 16-byte chunks into String only really works for fixed-with encodings, but MS949 seems to be a variable-length encoding, so this can easily break a variable-length sequence in half.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you beat me to it. I was about to say, @may are you sure you haven't swallowed any exceptions? You might have been lucky so far in that your characters could have been in the lower 'ascii' region but you could easily run into the problem that Joachim described, so the code as it stands is not valid. You need to collect the decrypted bytes in something like a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then encode as a MS949 in one go.

Comment: @G00SE I succeeded in using `ByteArrayOutputStream` to make outbuf an array of one byte and then get the textData the way I wanted. Thank you.
However, there is still a problem with imageData, and I have added content in this regard

Comment: I think at this point we need to see an example of the data. Preferably with a very small image