# My java Base64 results are not the same as php

Tags: java, php, base64

I have previously posted a question related to this work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356386/is-there-a-way-to-read-files-in-bytes/74357182#74357182) but I am posting a new one because the question is not completely resolved

I am working on converting the completed code into java with php.
It is a function that reads encrypted files, decrypts them by 16 bytes, makes them into a single string, and encodes them with base 64.
php is already on the server and running, and I have to use java to produce the same result.

If you decrypt the read file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FileInfo>
    ...
    <TextData> (text data) </TextData>
</FileInfo>
(image data)
```

It is in the format, and the text data in  shows php and java exactly the same.
I am trying to encode the image data part into base64, but the result is different from php.

This is the part of the php code I have that decrypts and processes the read file

```
        $fileContentArray = array(16);
        $transContentArray = array(16);
        $fileRead = fread($fp,16);

        for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($fileRead); $i++){
            $fileContentArray[$i] = ord($fileRead[$i]);
        }  
        $seed->SeedDecrypt($fileContentArray,$pdwRoundKey,$transContentArray); 
        $transStr =  call_user_func_array("pack",array_merge(array("C16"),$transContentArray));
        
        $mergeStr .=  $transStr;    
    }
    $dataExplode = explode("<TextData>",trim($mergeStr) );
    $dataExplode1 = explode("</FileInfo>",trim($dataExplode[1]) );
    $dataExplode2 = explode("</TextData>",$dataExplode1[0]);
    $textData = iconv("EUC-KR","utf-8",$dataExplode2[0]);
    $imageData = base64_encode(trim($dataExplode1[1]));
```

And this is the same part of the java code I wrote

```
                    byte[] fileContentArray=new byte[n];

                    for(int i=0;i<fileContentArray.length;i++){
                        fileContentArray[i]=mergeArr[nReadCur+i];
                    }
                    
                    
                    seed.SeedDecrypt(fileContentArray, pdwRoundKey, outbuf);
                    
                    System.arraycopy(outbuf, 0, resultArr, nReadCur, outbuf.length);
                    
                    nReadCur=nReadCur+fileContentArray.length;
                    p=p+fileContentArray.length;
                    if(p>=nFileSize){
                        fis.close();
                        break;   
                    }
                }//while
                
                mergeStr=new String(resultArr,"MS949");
                String[] dataExplode=mergeStr.trim().split("<TextData>");
                String[] dataExplode1=dataExplode[1].trim().split("</FileInfo>");
                String[] dataExplode2=dataExplode1[0].trim().split("</TextData>");

                String textData = "";
                String imageData = "";
                
                textData=dataExplode2[0];
                imageData=dataExplode1[1];
    
                Encoder encoder=Base64.getEncoder();
                Decoder decoder=Base64.getDecoder();
                byte[] encArr=encoder.encode(imageData.trim().getBytes("MS949"));
                imageData=new String(encArr,"MS949");
```

As a result of encoding image data into base64

php: `R0lGODlhAwNLBPcAAAAAAAAAMwAAZgAAmQAAzAAA/wArAAArMwArZgArmQArzAAr/wBVAABVMwBVZgBVmQBVzABV/wCAAACAMwCAZgCAmQCAzACA/ ... VzpYirO0le55zF0=`

java: `R0lGODlhAwNLBD8AAAAAAAAAMwAAZgAAPwAAPwAAPwArAAArMwArZgArPwArPwArPwBVAABVMwBVZgBVPwBVPwBVPwA/AAA/MwA/ZgA/PwA/PwA/PwA/ ... DAQEAOz9GPz8/IXY=`

As you can see, the result values are output differently.
Is there anything I'm missing? What should I do to make the result of java the same as php?

Also, MergeStr, who has read the file,

java:

```
GIF89aK?       3  f  ?  ?  ? +  +3 +f +? +? +? U  U3 Uf U? U? U? ?  ?3 ?f ?? ?? ?? ?  ?3 챖 첌 ぬ ? ?  ?3 ?f ??
...
J뇽杞H?*]苛⒢쬝쥻쒳뎁諾X...
A?h?~?0a?2$ @삁?d?Dd??e ...
...
WC ;홃?뿿!v
```

php:

```
GIF89aK?       3  f  ?  ?   +  +3 +f +? +? + U  U3 Uf U? U? U   3 f ? ?  ?  ? 챖 첌 ぬ ? ?  ? ? ? 螂 ?   3 f ? ? ...
A??~?a?$ @삁?d?Dd?e...
...
WC ;홃??v余퍙W:X뒽킉??
```

Like this, there is a new line text that I didn't put in, and there's a slight difference in result. Is this a simple difference in encoding? And does this affect the base64 conversion?

I tried encoding with UTF-8 and failed again,
and I used this code to load all bytes of the file at once

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tpf);
fis.read(mergeArr);
```

Comment: This part: `imageData.trim().getBytes("MS949")` fundamentally doesn't add up. You're treating characters as raw image byte data? That's.. just not possible. Characters aren't bytes; they are either Base64 or otherwise encoded, or, they are corrupted.

Comment: If you have image data in an XML file then you should be using a CDATA section. You should be decrypting the file and then using an XML parser to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a little bit different encoding for base64 than PHP. You may use these helper functions to make them compatible to the Java version.

```
function base64url_encode($data)
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data, $strict = false)
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), $strict);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I have to complete the java code without changing the result with the existing php code. And my base64 value is sent in json, not url

Comment: It's not about URL, it is about base64, but these chars are handled differently between Java and PHP. You will see immediately when using JWT, which are JSON. This is named url, because when using in a GET request, it will break without the replacements. So if you can't touch the PHP code, do those encoding on the Java side instead.